# ¿Problema al manejar 2 jquery.js de diferentes versiones?

Tags: c#, jquery, datatables

tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Tengo una vista _Layout que es la pagina principal con todas las librerias js y los menú y usa `jquery-1.11.1.js`.El problema es que cuando heredo esa pagina mediante RenderBody() en una nueva pagina estoy usando `jquery-3.3.1` para manipular ***DataTables*** y el error que me aparece es el siguiente

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

Verifique que el error es por las versiones del jquery e hice lo siguiente:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Mantenimiento Ruma";
    Layout = null; => Deje de heredar el Layout
}
```

y si me llega a funcionar el ***DataTable***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías utilizar [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).

En tu caso sería así:

```
<!-- load jQuery 1.11.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_1_11_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>

<!-- load jQuery 3.3.1 -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var jQuery_3_3_1 = $.noConflict(true);
</script>
```

Luego en vez de utilizar jQuery normalmente lo haces con la variable definida:

```
jQuery_3_3_1('#tuSeleccion').function();
```

Esto estoy seguro funcionaba para versiones más viejas, desconozco si con las nuevas no lo  siguen soportando pero puedes investigar en la página de jQuery que te pasé.

De todas formas, no te recomiendo tener varias versiones de librerías dentro de una misma solución, lo IDEAL sería migrar todo a la más reciente cuando no tenes presión para hacerlo, porque si luego encuentras un bug en la versión vieja y ya no recibes arreglos vas a tener un problema más serio.

Esto último claramente es un simple consejo.

Espero que te sirva!

Comment: y para el tema del css no trae problemas

Comment: Que yo sepa no, pero te repito que con versiones nuevas no estoy familiarizado, ya hace rato no trabajo con jQuery.